# How to handle nested property list

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, plist, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Good day!

I have a problem with doing a nested property list in iOS.

So, there are two `UITextField`s that will accept a random value and will then save it to a property list. The problem is, when I input a *second* value, it will overwrite the *first* value inside of my property list.

How do I handle, or write a nested property list?

Here's my attempted code:

```
- (IBAction)writeToPlist:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Write.");

    NSString *finalPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *fruitDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSString *fruitName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[fruitNameField text]];
    NSString *fruitDescription = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[fruitDescriptionField text]];

    NSDictionary *fruitDetail = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fruitName, fruitDescription, nil]
                                                            forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Fruit", @"Description", nil]];

    NSMutableDictionary *fruitPlist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
    NSMutableArray *fruitArray = [fruitPlist objectForKey:fruitName];

    if (fruitArray == nil) {
        fruitArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    [fruitDictionary setObject:fruitDetail forKey:fruitName];

    [fruitArray addObject:fruitDictionary];
    [fruitArray writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];

    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                        completion:nil];
}
```

The output is:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Apple</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Description</key>
            <string>Red</string>
            <key>Fruit</key>
            <string>Apple</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

What I want to happen is:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Apple</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Description</key>
            <string>Red</string>
            <key>Fruit</key>
            <string>Apple</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Banana</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Description</key>
            <string>Yellow</string>
            <key>Fruit</key>
            <string>Banana</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

By the way, is my code acceptable or not? I mean, is there any way I could shorten it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I played around with your code and Find out some problems.

here is what I wrote and tested. It is working.

```
  NSString *finalPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
  NSMutableDictionary *fruitDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  NSString *fruitName = fName;
  NSString *fruitDescription = fDetail;
  NSDictionary *fruitDetail = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fruitName, fruitDescription, nil]
                                                          forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Fruit", @"Description", nil]];
  NSMutableArray *fruitPlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];


if (fruitPlist == nil) {
        fruitPlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
  [fruitDictionary setObject:fruitDetail forKey:fruitName];
  [fruitPlist addObject:fruitDictionary];
  [fruitPlist writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
```

Explanation: 
You were getting the inner dictionary in your code a sroot of your plist. But instead  at the root you want to have NSArray. Thats why, this:

```
NSMutableArray *fruitPlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
```

In my code fName and fDetail are just variables I am passing.
Hope it helps!!

Comment: Data.plist won't appear inside the directory.

Comment: OOps!! i sort of forget to add array first time. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You are first retrieving a Dictionary from the plist and then writing an Array. One of the 2 is wrong.
Based on that you want to maybe try something like this:

```
    NSMutableArray *fruitPlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];

NSDictionary *newFruit;

for (NSDictionary *fruit in fruitPlist) {
    if ([fruit objectForKey:fruitName]) newFruit = fruit;
}

if (!newFruit) {
    newFruit = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    [fruitPlist addObject:newFruit];
}
else {
    NSInteger index = [fruitPlist indexOfObject:newFruit];

    // modify newFruit as you wish

    [fruitPlist replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:newFruit];

}

[fruitPlist writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: What do you usually put inside the else statement, where you have a comment? **EDIT:** it won't generate a Data plist.

Comment: the if else there is just a way to work with a new fruit (in the if statement) of a fruit that is already been created but you want to modify (in the else statement).